# Bloquear página PHP para só mostrar dados se for uma requisição AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tenho um arquivo `.php` que carrega e exibe todas as notícias do meu banco de dados, uso esse arquivo para carregar as notícias dinamicamente com AJAX. Até ai tudo bem, o usuário pode ir normalmente na página `index.html` e ver as notícias que foram carregadas via AJAX e PHP, mas o usuário também pode ir na página `noticias.php` e ver todas as notícias da página. Porém eu não queria isso, não tem como o PHP retornar dados para o AJAX ou algo do tipo? Para que o usuário não possa acessar diretamente o `noticias.php`?

Answer (score 6):

O que pode fazer verificar é em relação a `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
    AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {
    // se entrar aqui é uma chamada ajax
}
```

Comment: Entendi, não conhecia esse recurso, obrigado!

Comment: Q&A de interesse: [Does $_SERVER\['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'\] exist in PHP or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2579254/1287812)

Answer (score 3):

Concordo com a resposta do Marcelo Diniz no entanto quero dizer que a resposta pode de ser um pouco mais completa.

Para tornar a solução mais robusta além da verificação do `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` deverá ser também verificado o `HTTP_REFERER` pois assim poderá ser verificada a origem do `request`.

exemplo:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])
{
    header ("Location: index.php");<br>
}
```

Convém referir que ambas as situações podem ter conteúdos específicos pois se alguém mal intencionado assim o entender, estas duas variáveis podem ser facilmente falseadas. No entanto é sempre de aplicar pois despista a maior parte dos casos.

Quando a solução requer algo mais profissional, então aconselho trabalhar com `Sessions` e umas das variáveis irá conter um TOKEN diferente a cada chamada, desta forma o sistema tornou-se interno e quase impossível de falsear... mesmo com SessionHijacking.

Comment: obrigado Marcelo pela correcção na formatação do código presente na resposta